# Is a websocket connection secure after it's been established?

Tags: websocket

Provided that you somehow successfully established an authenticated secure websocket connection, would that connection be considered safe from then on? Meaning, do you have to send authentication data with each message so that if an attacker somehow connects to the already established websocket, they can't send anything meaningful? I assume for wss connections such a condition can't occur, but what about a regular ws connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WebSocket is a point-to-point connection, so nobody else can connect to **that particular** socket. If you're using current cyphers for the TLS, then this should be secure (there are cyphers out there which are being deprecated at the moment since they are/may be broken).

For a non-TLS WebSocket connection the same goes as for anything done over regular HTTP (or any other unencrypted protocol): any intermediary can alter the data, so this cannot be considered secure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good 2 part blog post on WebSocket security that should help you:

http://blog.kaazing.com/2012/02/28/html5-websocket-security-is-strong/